# C# EF core exception "The property '' on entity type '' has a temporary value"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

У меня выскочила странная ошибка. Существуют три таблицы:

 Клас Users описывает данные пользователя. 
Клас words_inDictionary содержит информацию о иностраном слове.
Клас WordsUsers является промежуточной таблицей для формирования связи многи-ко-многим (Один пользователь может учить много слов и одно слово может учится многими пользователями). В промежуточной таблице существует 3 ключа - один первичный и два внешних.

```
public class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        Words = new List<WordsUsers>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(60)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<WordsUsers> Words { get; set; }
}

public class Word_InDictiononary
{
    public Word_InDictiononary()
    {
        Users = new List<WordsUsers>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string Word { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Word_Translated { get; set; }

    public List<WordsUsers> Users { get; set; }
}

public class WordsUsers
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int UsersID { get; set; }
    public Users User { get; set; }

    public int Word_InDictionaryID { get; set; }
    public Word_InDictiononary Word_InDictiononary { get; set; }
}
```

FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<WordsUsers>()
    .HasKey(t=> new { t.ID, t.UsersID, t.Word_InDictionaryID });

modelBuilder
    .Entity<WordsUsers>()
    .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
    .WithMany(s => s.Words)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.UsersID);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<WordsUsers>()
    .HasOne(sc => sc.Word_InDictiononary)
    .WithMany(s => s.Users)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.Word_InDictionaryID);
```

Мой вопрос следующий : 
При попытке добавления что-либо в эту таблицу выкидывается Exception странного происхождения:

> Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ID' on entity type 'WordsUsers' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Что не так со свойством ID класа WordsUsers?

Comment: EF умеет сам создавать связь многие ко многим за кулисами, зачем вы делаете это вручную?

Comment: В промежуточной таблице мне нужно было так же уникальный идентификатор и еще несколько дополнительный полей, но здесь я их опустил, т.к. они здесь не важны.

Comment: Покажите как вы добавляете

Comment: Я немного запутался в вашем коде и причиной всему - плохой нейминг. Дам пару совсетов: `Word_InDictiononary` - используйте `CamelCaseNaming`. Далее, множественное число `WordsUsers` - может тут логичнее видеть `WordUsers`, а вообще для класса по-хорошему бы посавить имя `WordUser`. Почему то список `List<WordsUsers>` называется `Words` - не логично и вводит в заблуждение.  В одном месте `List<WordsUsers>` называется `Words` а в другом месте `Users` - нужно навести порядок. Также, используйте `ICollection` вместо `List`, посмотрите примеры EF. Составной ключ выглядит нелепо - пересмотрите его.